# how to dockerize a codeigniter app with a database.sql using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, codeigniter-3

I'm new to Docker. I have a CodeIgniter project and its database.sql runing on my localhost (XAMPP). I want to host my project on Docker.

Would anyone be able to provide some guidance as to how I would write a docker-compose.yml using apache, php and mysql containers using my database.sql as a init file.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question is quite big, and hard to give you a whole solution answer. I believe out there are a lot of examples related to your questions (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371440/how-to-containerise-codeigniter-project-using-docker/64373022). Give it a try and when you stuck somewhere then with a particular question it easier to give you an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to containerise CodeIgniter project using Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371440/how-to-containerise-codeigniter-project-using-docker)